# Creating a database from various web pages?

Tags: java, python, database, web, web-scraping

Is there a way using java or python that I can somehow gather a ton of information from a ton of different colleges on a website such as collegeboard?

I want to know how to do things like this but I've never really programmed outside of default libraries. I have no idea how to start my approach.

Example:

> I input a large list of colleges on a list that looks somewhat like
>   this
>
> https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/print-college-search-results
>
> The code then finds the page for each college such as
>
> https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/college-university-search/alaska-bible-college?searchType=college&q=AlaskaBibleCollege
>
> and then gathers information from the page such as tuition, size, etc.
>
> and then stores it in a class that I can use for analysis and stuff

Is something like this even possible? I remember seeing a similar program in the Social Network. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So, short answer, yes. It's perfectly possible, but you need to learn a bunch of stuff first:**

1) The basics of the DOM model (HTML) so you can parse the page
2) The general idea of how servers and databases work (and how to interface with them in python- what I use, or java)
3) Sort of a subsection of 2: Learn how to retrieve HTML documents from a server to then parse

**Then, once you do that, this is the procedure a program would haft to go through:**

1) You need to come up with a list of pages that you want to search. If you want to search and entire website, you need to sort of narrow that down. You can easily limit your program to just search certain types of forums, which all have the same format on college board. You'll also want to add part of the program that builds a list of web pages that your program finds links to. For instants, if collegeboard has a page with a bunch of links to different pages with statistics, you'll want your program to scan that page to find the links to the pages with those statistics.

2) You need to find the ID, location, or some identifying marker of the HTML tag that contains the information you want. If you want to get REALLY FANCY (and I mean REALLY fancy) you can try to use some algorithms to parse the text and try to get information (maybe trying to parse admission statistics and stuff from the text on the forums)

3) You then need to store that information in a database that you then index and create an interface to search (if you want this whole thing to be online, I suggest the python framework Django for making it a web application). For the database type, it would make sense to use Sqlite 3 (I)

**So yes, it's perfectly possible, but here's the bad news:**

1) As someone already commented, you'll need to figure out step 2 for each individual web page format you do. (By web page format, I mean different pages with different layouts. The stack overflow homepage is different from this page, but all of the question pages follow the same format)

2) Not only will you need to repeat step 2 for each new website, but if the website does a redesign, you'll have to redo it again as well.

3) By the time you finish the program you may have easily gathered the info on your own.

**Alternative and Less Cool Option**

Instead of going through all the trouble or searching the web page for specific information, you can just search the web page and extract all its text, then try and find key words within the text relating to colleges.

BUT WAIT, THERE'S SOMETHING THAT DOES THIS ALREADY! It's called google :). That's basically how google works, so... yah.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand it won't be easy but I want to be able to somewhat "fish" for mass information like this. I feel like there are a lot of situations where it can be useful.

Comment: I just added a bit to the post. You know, your not going to be able to apply this program to other types of information. Every time you want to make something like this, your going to have to spend hours, if not days, finding every site that you want to get information from, mapping out the entire thing and searching for it.

Comment: Just added an "Alternative and less cool option". Just a heads up, when someone answers your question, you can check off the check next to it. Not that I have answered your question necessarily, but if someone does, it's polite to check it off.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is "a way". But there is no **easy way**.

You need to write a bunch of code that extracts the stuff you are interested in from the HTML.  Then you need to write code to turn that information into a form that matches your database schema ... and do the database updates.

There are tools that help with parts of the problem; e.g. Web crawler frameworks for fetching the pages, JSoup for parsing HTML, Javascript engines if the pages are "dynamic", etc.  But I'm not aware of anything that does the whole job.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about here is called [scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping) and in general
it's quite tricky to do right. You have to worry about a bunch of
things:

1. The data is formatted for display, not programmatic consumption.
   It may be messy, inconsistent, or incomplete.
2. There may be dynamic content, which means you might have to run a
   JavaScript VM or something just to get the final state of the page.
3. The format could change, often.

So I'd say the first thing you should do is see if you can access the
data some other way before you resort to scraping. If you poke around
in the source for those pages, you might find a webservice feeding data
to the display layer in XML or JSON. That would be a much better place
to start.

Answer (score 0):

Ok everyone thanks for the help. Here's how I ended up doing it. It took me a little while but thankfully collegeboard uses very simple addresses.

Basically there are 3972 colleges and each has a unique, text only page with an address that goes like:

https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/print-college-profile?id=9

but the id=(1-3972).

Using a library called HTMLunit I was able to access all of these pages, convert them in to strings and then gather the info using indexOf.

It still is going to take about 16 hours to process all of them but I've got a hundred or so saved.

Maybe I lucked out with the print page but I got what I needed and thanks for the help!